# Why did countries initially presume that detecting COVID-19 requires a deep nasal swab?

Tags: covid-19

According to a [recent paper](https://www.medrxiv.org/content/10.1101/2020.04.16.20067835v1):

> To validate the use of saliva for                           SARS-CoV-2
>   detection, we tested nasopharyngeal and saliva samples from confirmed 
>   COVID-19 patients and self-collected samples from healthcare workers
>   on COVID-19                     wards. When we compared SARS-CoV-2
>   detection from patient-matched nasopharyngeal               and saliva
>   samples, we found that saliva yielded greater detection sensitivity
>   and      consistency throughout the
>   course of infection. Furthermore, we report less variability in
>   self-sample collection of saliva. Taken together, our findings
>   demonstrate that saliva is a                           viable and more
>   sensitive alternative to nasopharyngeal swabs and could enable at-home
>   self-administered sample collection for accurate large-scale
>   SARS-CoV-2 testing.

This made me wonder... why did countries initially presume that deep nasal swabs are the default route for detecting the virus? Why didn't we start out with basic saliva samples and then try out invasive sampling, rather than the other way around?

Comment: This article is a preprint and has not been certified by peer review.  Also interesting statement within the paper "Although nasopharyngeal swabs are commonly used in respiratory virus diagnostics, they                
show **relatively poor sensitivity** for SARS-CoV-2 detection in early infection and are                        
**inconsistent** during serial testing.(bolding added)

Comment: Some other [recent (case) studies](https://annals.org/aim/fullarticle/2764963/sars-cov-2-isolation-from-ocular-secretions-patient-covid-19) have even suggested SARS-CoV-2 persists even longer in the eyes (ocular fluids), so it should it be sampled from there. YMMV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the paper you linked to

> nasopharyngeal swabs are commonly used in respiratory virus diagnostics

So clearly it was preferred for Covid-19 because of the "received wisdom" from other respiratory virus illnesses. (To pick a random example, the [2005 WHO guidlines](https://www.who.int/influenza/human_animal_interface/virology_laboratories_and_vaccines/guidelines_collection_h5n1_humans/en/) for avian influenza don't mention saliva samples, but various kinds of swabs and washes (for the upper respiratory tract): nasal swab,
nasopharyngeal swab, nasopharyngeal aspirate, nasal wash, throat swab.)

If you want to ask why saliva sampling is not a method more widely used (instead of, or, in addition to nasopharyngeal swabs) in *other* respiratory virus diagnostics, modify your question according (incl. tag).

Comment: I'll just tag along with Fizz on this and add... because that (nasopharyngeal) is prescribed in the manufacturer's test protocols. (for example the Abbott IN NOW [ https://www.fda.gov/media/136525/download ]

Comment: And those WHO guidelines further specify that Nasopharyngeal aspiration (NPA) was the preferred method... which is not inconsistent with [other studies](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2658151/) except that's even more unpleasant than the swabs https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18242124

Comment: Here's a follow up: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/23388/why-isnt-saliva-sampling-used-when-sampling-for-the-presence-of-respiratory-dis